# 少しはマシになってきたな meaning

Tags: grammar, meaning

Without context can it mean a couple of things/ have a double meaning? Like 'you're looking better' 'things are looking better' 'it looks better'

The person who said it talked about two different things that might connect to it before saying this, the other person's face looking unhealthy and a bad situation involving the other person.

Answer (score 2):

Without context, this sentence is not tricky, deep nor playful at all. It just says "(Something) is getting at least a little better than before (although it's still bad)", where the subject is usually something mentioned in the existing context/sentence. Perhaps you are overthinking something, or you are missing some background story.